# Let users leave comment on order what will display on product page WOOCOMMERCE

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, comments

I have the following problem: I would like for users when they buy at my Woocommerce shop to type an message like 'Thanks man!' on checkout. Then, after the checkout was succesfull I would like to have this comment places directly on the product page they just bought something off.

Does anybody know if this is possible, and how?

Best regards,
Bas.

Comment: thats too broad. you should show us the code on the thanks page and what you attempted to do what you want

Comment: Add an 'event' when a checkout completes that takes the message and insert it to database and then show it on the product page OR just add the code on the checkout file.

Comment: This feature is called reviews and already exist in Woocommerce. Now to get something custom without providing any code is just too broad for stackOver Flow. Please remember that stackOver Flow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Thank you all for the commands, I am talking about Woocommerce so I did not include any custom code because I am looking for A way to implent this in Woocommerce. On the checkout you have fields like 'Comments' I would like to show these values directly on the product page after checkout. I was wondering of there was any standard Woocommerce code or maby plugin. Best regards,

Comment: I believe there's a plugin called Checkout Field Editor which allows you to add fields to your liking and you can edit your theme file to show the comments on the page.

Comment: @PlanetCloud Would you happen to know how to implent this in the theme? Or where I can find this information?

Comment: @HomanBas, You did not mention any theme above and here's the plugin page : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/. It should work with any theme...